# Alignment of text in Qt Combobox

Tags: android, qt, qml

I have a combobox in Qt and some items in it. Now the problem is, when the text is too long and the item is selected, the right side of the item is shown and I want to show the left side (the beginning) of the text and ... at the end (the rest of the text that won't fit in the box will not be shown) Is there a way of doing this? . I have been searching the whole internet and documentations but I did not find a proper answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way to do this currently. You need to provide a custom delegate for the `ComboBox` itself, and then override its `contentItem` to be able to set the `elide` property:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 400

    ComboBox {
        id: comboBox
        model: [ "some really really really long text", "some really really really long text" ]
        delegate: ItemDelegate {
            id: itemDelegate
            width: parent.width
            text: comboBox.textRole ? (Array.isArray(comboBox.model) ? modelData[comboBox.textRole] : model[comboBox.textRole]) : modelData
            font.weight: comboBox.currentIndex === index ? Font.DemiBold : Font.Normal
            highlighted: comboBox.highlightedIndex === index
            hoverEnabled: comboBox.hoverEnabled

            contentItem: Label {
                text: itemDelegate.text
                font: itemDelegate.font
                elide: Label.ElideRight
                verticalAlignment: Label.AlignVCenter
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I copied the `delegate` implementation from [here](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols2.git/tree/src/imports/controls/ComboBox.qml?id=d09a7a6a344743fc01a34d153d1bd3384e77c1d7#n56).

I think it could make sense for `ItemDelegate` (or rather `AbstractButton`, so that all of its derivatives could benefit from it) to have an `elide` property, so that it's one less custom item.

Comment: Thanks for answer, i often found something like this but I needed a little behind-the-code talk :P well, Ill try and let u know

Comment: If you have any questions about the code, feel free to ask.

Comment: Okay, so I am facing one problem... we have the text of the ComboBox  solved by TextField, not a Label, which makes it hard to elide it whereas this property is not in a TextField... can I solve this problem with a TextField?

Comment: Hmmm, ComboBox already supports editing items via the `editable` property. Just curious: is there any reason you can't use that feature instead? There is no elide property for `TextField` unfortunately. The closest thing you can do would be to hide the `TextField` when it's not being edited and then show a `Label` in its place instead (and set the eliding on that).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help, I put more effort in it today and found an easy way of doing it here : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textmetrics.html
Thing is I used TextMetrics and filled it with combo box text and then used the textmetrics text in the textfield